# JSFiddle & Callbacks

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, jsfiddle

As part of an exericse, I'm re-writing underscore functions and testing them in jsfiddle. Every time I pass a callback function, I get "undefined".

My code is below:

```
each = function(collection, iterator) {
if(Array.isArray(collection)){
  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    iterator(collection[i], i, collection);
  }
} else {
  for(var key in collection) {
    iterator(collection[key], key, collection);
  }
}
};

var numbers = [1,2,3,4];

var result = each(numbers, function(num) {
 return num * 2;
});

 console.log(result);
// undefined
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and why it's not outputting on jsfiddle?

Comment: `each()` doesn't `return` anything itself. `return num * 2;` doesn't automatically make the jump to `var result` without `each()` cooperating.

Comment: Your each function is not returning any value

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s959rs8w/1/

Comment: Just curious, because running the code on jsfiddle 2 days ago worked. Also, the exercise is part of the Underbar exercises, and the tests pass locally without a return statement. Any ideas? [Underbar](https://github.com/RayMan504/Underbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong.  Your `each` function isn't returning anything.  This is fine, since `each` functions don't necessarily have to return anything.  You might be thinking along the lines of a `map` or `reduce` function which compile the results of calling the callback on each item in the collection, and then return that compilation.

The callback you pass to an `each` function doesn't normally return anything.  Think of an `each` like it's just syntactic sugar for a normal `for` loop; `for` loops don't return anything (obviously..), they just perform generic operations with the items in the collection and the variables that have been declared in the containing scope.

That being said, if you want to emulate underscore (or any good library), you will want to return the collection to enable chaining.  From the [underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org/#each):

> [each] Iterates over a list of elements, yielding each in turn to an iteratee function....Returns the list for chaining.

This is just good practice so as to avoid annoying the developers who may use your library and are used to being able to chain everything in JavaScript.

So all you'd need to do is put

```
return collection;
```

at the end of your `each` function and you're good.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @bowheart , excellent explanation! I seem to have my map and each mixed up. All clarified now!

Answer (score 0):

You are not aggregating the result of your operation that's why the result is not being result.

Here is a quick stab at how this can be fixed for arrays.

```
each = function(collection, iterator) {
    var arr = [];
    if(Array.isArray(collection)){
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        arr.push( iterator(collection[i], i, collection) );
    }
    return arr;
    } else {
    for(var key in collection) {
      iterator(collection[key], key, collection);
    }
    }
};

var numbers = [1,2,3,4];

var result = each(numbers, function(num) {
 return num * 2;
});

 console.log(result);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emm4rjy8/)